# Ubuntu 18.04 running Apache 2.4.29, `apt upgrade` doesn't find latest version (2.4.46)?

Tags: security, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, lamp, apt

Running a LAMP server with Apache installed (from stock repositories via `apt install apache2`).  `apt upgrade` shows no updates available, no held back packages, and `apache2 -v` shows 2.4.29, yet 2.4.46 is the latest version.  There's security fixes I'd like to apply per Apache's changelog.

Not sure which question is the right question, but here goes:

1. How can I update to Apache 2.4.46? and/or why doesn't `apt-update` detect the newer version?
2. I've read that some security upgrades are backported as long as you're not beyond end-of-life.  Could this be the case, but still reporting v 2.4.29?

Answer (score -1):

Basically, it's a question of repositories. As far as I understand, the "stock" repositories in Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't offer Apache2 versions above 2.4.29.

A possible workaround is described here (it only involves adding and installing from another repository, so the referenced version number (2.2.4.34) should be of no consequence):

https://websiteforstudents.com/install-the-latest-apache2-2-4-34-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-lts-servers/